# Can't get controller test working with RSpec 2 and edge Rails 3

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-3

Not sure if this is a Rails 3 issue or an RSpec 2 issue, but I can't seem to get a standard controller test working - it seems that the 'get' method can't be found.

I have a controller test that looks like this (named `discrepancies_controller_spec.rb` in `spec/controllers` directory):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DiscrepanciesController do
  before :each do
    Discrepancy.delete_all
  end

  it "resolves a discrepancy" do
 discrepancy = Discrepancy.create(:my_number=>"12345", :status=>"Open")

 get :resolve, :id => discrepancy.id

 retrieved_discrepancy = Discrepancy.find_by_my_number("12345")
 retrieved_discrepancy.status.should == "Resolved"
  end
end
```

(Yes, I'm aware of the security implications of modifying data with an HTTP/GET - that's a separate issue...)

When I run it with rake, I get the following error:

```
1) DiscrepanciesController resolves a discrepanc
    Failure/Error: Unable to find C to read failed line
    undefined method `get' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0xc9170d0 @__memoized={}>
    # ./spec/controllers/discrepancies_controller_spec.rb:38 (ignore the line number, commented out code was removed from the sample)
    # C:/Users/Patrick_Gannon/.bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/rails-16a5e918a06649ffac24fd5873b875daf66212ad-master/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:212:in `inject'
    # C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19:in `load'
    # C:/Ruby187/bin/rake:19
```

I can manage to test the controller action by instantiating the controller myself and calling the controller action directly, and it works, but its ugly because I have to mock out things like `respond_to` and `params`.

Other pertinent information: I am running Windows 7 32-bit, Ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i386-wingw32], edge Rails 3 and MongoDB/MongoMapper.  Here is my list of installed gems (via 'bundle gem' - all my installed gems were installed by Bundler)

- abstract (1.0.0)
- actionmailer (3.0.0.beta4)
- actionpack (3.0.0.beta4)
- activemodel (3.0.0.beta4)
- activerecord (3.0.0.beta4)
- activeresource (3.0.0.beta4)
- activesupport (3.0.0.beta4)
- arel (0.4.0)
- bcrypt-ruby (2.1.2)
- bson (1.0.3)
- bson_ext (1.0.1)
- builder (2.1.2)
- bundler (0.9.26)
- capistrano (2.5.19)
- capybara (0.3.8 a94f99)
- cucumber (0.8.3)
- cucumber-rails (0.3.2 master-b75110)
- culerity (0.2.10)
- database_cleaner (0.5.2 7ea99d)
- devise (1.1.rc1 88ab2f)
- diff-lcs (1.1.2)
- erubis (2.6.5)
- factory_girl (1.3.0)
- factory_girl_rails (1.0)
- faker (0.3.1)
- ffi (0.6.3)
- gherkin (2.0.2)
- highline (1.5.2)
- i18n (0.4.1)
- jnunemaker-validatable (1.8.4)
- joint (0.3.2 11a094)
- json_pure (1.4.3)
- mail (2.2.5)
- mime-types (1.16)
- mongo (1.0.3)
- mongo_mapper (0.8.2)
- net-scp (1.0.2)
- net-sftp (2.0.4)
- net-ssh (2.0.23)
- net-ssh-gateway (1.0.1)
- nokogiri (1.4.2.1)
- plucky (0.3.2)
- polyglot (0.3.1)
- rack (1.1.0)
- rack-mount (0.6.6)
- rack-test (0.5.4)
- rails (3.0.0.beta4 6682cc)
- railties (3.0.0.beta4)
- rake (0.8.7)
- rspec (2.0.0.beta.13)
- rspec-core (2.0.0.beta.13)
- rspec-expectations (2.0.0.beta.13)
- rspec-mocks (2.0.0.beta.13)
- rspec-rails (2.0.0.beta.13)
- selenium-webdriver (0.0.24)
- term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
- thor (0.13.6)
- treetop (1.4.8)
- trollop (1.16.2)
- tzinfo (0.3.22)
- wand (0.2.1)
- warden (0.10.7)
- webrat (0.7.1)

I also added a puts statement in the test to show what methods are available in the test fixture (`(methods - Object.methods).sort.inspect`), and "get" is not in the list.  Here is what is in the list:

```
"__memoized", "__should_for_example_group__", "__should_not_for_example_group__", "_fixture_class_names", "_fixture_path", "_fixture_table_names", "_pre_loaded_fixtures", "_setup_mocks", "_teardown_mocks", "_use_instantiated_fixtures", "_use_transactional_fixtures", "_verify_mocks", "a_kind_of", "allow_message_expectations_on_nil", "an_instance_of", "any_args", "anything", "assert", "assert_block", "assert_equal", "assert_in_delta", "assert_instance_of", "assert_kind_of", "assert_match", "assert_nil", "assert_no_match", "assert_not_equal", "assert_not_nil", 
"assert_not_same", "assert_nothing_raised", "assert_nothing_thrown", "assert_operator", "assert_raise", "assert_raises", "assert_respond_to", "assert_same", "assert_send", "assert_throws", "be", "be_a", "be_a_kind_of", "be_a_new", "be_an", "be_an_instance_of", "be_close", "be_false", "be_instance_of", "be_kind_of", "be_nil", "be_true", "boolean", "build_message", "change", "described_class", "double", "duck_type", "eq", "eql", "equal", "example", "example=", "exist", "expect", "fixture_class_names", "fixture_class_names?", "fixture_path", "fixture_path?", "fixture_table_names", 
"fixture_table_names?", "flunk", "hash_including", "hash_not_including", "have", "have_at_least", "have_at_most", "have_exactly", "include", "instance_of", "kind_of", "match", "method_missing", "method_name", "mock", "mock_discrepancy", "mock_model", "no_args", "pending", "pre_loaded_fixtures", "pre_loaded_fixtures?", "raise_error", "respond_to", "run_in_transaction?", "running_example", "satisfy", "setup_fixtures", "stub_model", "subject", "teardown_fixtures", "throw_symbol", "use_instantiated_fixtures", "use_instantiated_fixtures?", "use_transactional_fixtures", "use_transactional_fixtures?"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got an answer to this on the RSpec mailing list from David Chelimsky, as follows:

I'm surprised this is the first time this has come up with rspec-2, but here we are :)

This is a path-separator bug that I'll resolve in the next release. For now, you can do this in your controller specs:

```
describe DiscrepanciesController do
  include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup
```

That should work fine.

If you want to do a more global workaround, add this to your spec_helper config:

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include RSpec::Rails::ControllerExampleGroup, :example_group => { :file_path => /\bspec[\\\/]controllers[\\\/]/ }
end
```